# Dynamic Magento SOAP request

Tags: php, magento, soap

I want to update Magento articles through the Magento PHP SOAP API.

This request works fine:

```
$result = $soap->catalogProductUpdate($session_id, $res[0]['sku'], array(
    'price' => '69,99'
));
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
$result = $soap->catalogProductUpdate($session_id, $res[0]['sku'], array(
    $_POST['t0'] => '69,99'
));
```

The variable `$_POST['t0']` contains the string that I want to update, in this case `$_POST['t0']` = `'price'`.

But it does not work. Any idea how to use post-variables as an array-key?